# How to draw a heart using css only?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How to draw a heart using only the **css** properties and html?
I have came across few codes to draw it but couldn't understand why do they use the **before** and **after** properties

**css code**

```
.heart {  
     background-color: red;  
      height: 30px;  
      transform: rotate(-45deg);  
      width: 30px;  
}  
.heart:before,  
.heart:after {    
      content: "";  
      background-color: red;  
      border-radius: 50%;  
      height: 30px;  
      position: absolute;  
      width: 30px;  
}  
.heart:before {    
      top: -15px;  
      left: 0;  
}
```

How the **before** and **after** properties work?
Would be helpful if someone could come up with alternate approach :)

Edits:- I just wanted to know why do we use the **before** and **after** properties and how it helps in creating this heart shape.
Also I'm looking for some easy and simple code(**using only css**) to obtain this shape.

Comment: Add your HTML to this, so we can understand the way you work. Also, before and after needs a display property.

Comment: @PierreBurton they don't need a display property .. the position:absolute is enough to make them block by default

Comment: Why do we need to add the display property?

Comment: The position which is set to absolute is fair enough :)

Comment: Heart with Pulse Animation : https://youtu.be/Jq4diUd10Zs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with pseudo elements

> **To learn more about pseudo elements**
>
> - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp
> - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/
> - https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/pseudo-element-before-after/

```css
body{
  padding-left:50px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 175px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(315deg);
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

div:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 175px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I wish I could have upvoted this answer but I don't have enough reputations to upvote this :(

Comment: @3251_ali Thanks mate for appreciation.. no worries, upvote when you have access in future.. hope soon ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea with only background and less of code:

```css
.heart {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
   radial-gradient(circle at 50% 83%, red 29%, transparent 30%) -40px -100px/100% 100%,
   radial-gradient(circle at 50% 83%, red 29%, transparent 30%) 40px -100px/100% 100%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom left/50% 50%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom right/50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
</div>
```

You can integrate CSS variable to control the dimensions:

```css
.heart {
  --d:200px;
  width:var(--d);
  height:var(--d);
  background:
   radial-gradient(circle at 50% 83%, red 29%, transparent 30%) calc(-1 * var(--d)/5) calc(-1 * var(--d)/2)/100% 100%,
   radial-gradient(circle at 50% 83%, red 29%, transparent 30%) calc(var(--d)/5) calc(-1 * var(--d)/2)/100% 100%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom left/50% 50%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 43%,transparent 43%) bottom right/50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
</div>
<div class="heart" style="--d:100px;">
</div>
<div class="heart" style="--d:50px;">
</div>
```

Comment: 1+, but the circles' position seems a little off, as they create some sort of edge, maybe some of the values need a little tweaking.

Comment: But this is not as perfect as I want it to be :(

Comment: @Maharkus we can always adjust ;) this is a simple and fast idea to avoid a lot of code

Comment: Yeah I know I'm nitpicking but I'm pretty sure OP doesn't have sufficient knowledge of CSS gradient, which is why I mentioned it :)

Comment: @Maharkus I updated to make it better ;)

Comment: @3251_ali check again, it should be better ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `before` and `after` tags are so called pseudo-elements. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) a helpful resource with more information on them. Basically it creates an element, that isn't there in the actual DOM (the HTML structure) and allows you to apply CSS styling to it.

In this case the `before` and `after` are two circles.

**Here's how a single pseudo element looks like in your case:**

```css
body {
  padding: 15px
}

.heart {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.heart:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
}

.heart:after {
  left: 15px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

**And here's the complete heart itself:**

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.heart {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 30px;
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
}

.heart:before {
  left: 0;
  top: -15px;
}

.heart:after {
  left: 15px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

If you rotate the main block you get a rotated square. The two pseudo elements being circles create a heart with the div itself, if the position of each element is fitting. The reason your heart wasn't working properly is because the pseudo elements weren't placed correctly. Pushing the `after` element to the left fixes this problem.

Comment: Is their any alternate approach to draw it?

Comment: Yes, @Temani_Afif covered this with gradients, alternatively, as already suggested SVG is also a possible approach.